# Select only parent node in Fancytree with hierarchical multiselection

Tags: fancytree

We have used Fancytree to have hierarchical multiselection. Now here is an issue

```
Parent 1
|
Parent 2
|-Child 21
|-Child 22
```

We have the above tree structure. When someone select Parent 2, both Child 21 and Child 22 are selected. Now the issue is if I unselect Child 21 and Child 22, the Parent 2 also gets unselected. I am looking for a way to have user the ability to select just the parent node, if user unselects the child nodes of that parent. Is it possible in FancyTree?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `selectMode: 2` and implement the desired functionality in the `select`/`deselect` events, by calling `node.select()` as required.